# How do I use the "IF statement" to select numbers from a range?

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, range

I have a set of measurements ranging from 1 to 30. Any number between 1 and 10 is "Good", any number between 11 and 24 is "Mild" while any number from 25 to 30 is "Bad". I hope to use the IF statement to do this classification but I have am yet to get it right. I have tried the following:

```
=IF((1<=A2<=10),"Good",IF((11<=A2<=24),"Mild",IF(A2>=25,"Bad")))
```

I would appreciate your kind suggestions on the most effective way to get this done.

Comment: @PeterB, courtesy of your kind response, I have realized my mistakes. I have got the formula right. Can you post your comment as an answer so I can mark it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel there is no `IF(x <= A <= y, ...)` .
The commonly used alternative is `IF(AND(x <= A, A <= y), ...)`.

Reference:

- [AND function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/and-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9)
- [IF function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)
- [IF: nested formulas and avoiding pitfalls](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-%E2%80%93-nested-formulas-and-avoiding-pitfalls-0b22ff44-f149-44ba-aeb5-4ef99da241c8)